# Building an embeddable component

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some insight into how I would go about making a component on my site embeddable by other users.

In it's most basic form, it's little widget that does calculations. But It needs to be able to be shared. Since I can't guarantee technologies used, I would imagine javascript is the way to go.

It's currently built using jquery and a bit of raphael js and also has its own css styling.

Comment: You could make another HTML file with just the embeddable part so others could use a `<iframe>` tag to embed it.

Comment: I think that's the route I was going to go, but I wanted to see if there was a better or more proper way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: How about building components using [Polymer JS](https://www.polymer-project.org/)??